# Transfer cookies from Android app to .NET webservice

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, authentication, cookies

I have an Android application (written in Java) that communicates with an ASP.NET webservice. The Android app is a forum reader that should display a list of threads in a forum and allow users to read the threads. The app merely contacts the webservice in the background and basically asks "give me the posts in thread x". The webservice then connects to the forum, downloads the HTML source code, parses it, and finally returns (in json format) the relevant information (each post along with the author, date, message, etc). The Android app then receives that information and displays it nicely.

In this way the webservice does all the 'dirty work' (downloading the forum HTML source, parsing it and extracting the relevant information), while the Android app merely sits back and receives the information it wants.

However, in order for the webservice to access the forum and its page source, the user must be authenticated. I can give the webservice access to the forum by doing a HTTP POST with the username and password to the login page of the forum, and storing the CookieContainer it receives when successfull. Then I use that same CookieContainer object in all further requests, which is enough to authenticate the user and allow access to the threads and their page source.

The obvious downside is that any users beside myself will have to enter their password in the Android app, which would have to send it to the webservice, which finally uses it to authenticate the user. The webservice needs the password in plain text obviously, hence it cannot receive a hashed version. I can of course encrypt the password or use HTTPS, but the fact remains that this way I require the plaintext password on the webservice, where I could potentially store it and steal passwords. Obviously not the best method.

The only alternative I can think about is doing the login work on the Android app itself, receive the CookieContainer there (I guess there must be something similar in Java?), and send that cookie information to the webservice instead. This would still allow 'hackers' to impersonate themselves as another user by intercepting the data, but as far as I can see it's no less secure then people simply logging on to the forum via the Android webbrowser. The obvious advantage is that I no longer need the plaintext password on the webservice site, the Android app does not need to send it to me (only to the (https) login page, same as if they used the browser directly) and there is no way for it to get intercepted or for me to steal it.

Long story short: I want to receive cookies from a webrequest in Java (the Android app), and somehow transfer them to a webservice (ASP.NET) where I can rebuild the CookieContainer object and use it for further requests. I must therefore somehow translate the cookies I get in Java to string(s), and send them to the webservice, where I rebuild a CookieContainer object out of those strings.

I tried some basic approaches but I'm getting nowhere. Can anyone assist me with this step?

Currently, in the ASP.NET webservice, I create a new CookieContainer object and use it as the CookieContainer property of the HttpWebRequest object. Then I execute a HTTP POST request to the login page, and if successfull that same CookieContainer object can be used to authenticate any further requests. I have to rewrite this basically in Java, only instead of using the CookieContainer directly (or whatever the equivalent is in Java), I need to convert it to a string so I can send it to the webservice, where I can rebuild the CookieContainer from the string.

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a login activity (native would probably work best). Have the login activity fire the post directly to the forum and get the cookie. If the login is successful, send the cookie to your webservice and it can store it and use it for subsequent requests from that device (assuming you are tracking devices on the webservice). If you don't want to track devices, have the Android app send the cookie as part of every request and have the webservice just pass it on.

Comment: That's the idea, yes. I would send the cookie with each request. But I don't know the specifics - how to send the cookie to the webservice? I'd have to convert the cookie on the Java side to some sort of string, so I can send it to the webservice, then build a new set of cookies from that string. That's what I'm trying to do right now, as a test I'm just sending the cookie values I'm seeing by using the Chrome developer tools, but even then it's not working, I think there's some problem with the domain of the cookies...